# Unable to use sql azure database value in web service

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, azure, type-conversion

I've created a database in sql azure. I'm trying to call the value i have put in my sql azure and return it in my web service. I added a connection to sql azure in my web.config file like this below

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString"connectionString="Server=tcp:vvigan1a71.database.windows.net,1433;Database=(myname);User  ID=(myid);Password=(myownpassword);Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In my webservice file(asmx), i try to establish connection like this below.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

I also declared 2 different variable i will use to call the value from the sql azure like shown below

```
double taxafter30k = Convert.ToDouble("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue");
double taxafter50k = Convert.ToDouble("Select taxafter50k from TaxValue");
```

I tried to call the method i have declared above into my web service

```
double totalcartaxOMV = 0d;

            if (carValue <= 20000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = carValue;
            }
            else if (carValue > 20000 && carValue <= 50000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * taxafter30k)));
            }
            else if (carValue > 50000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = (20000 + 42000 + ((carValue - 50000) * taxafter50k));
            }

        return totalcartaxOMV;
    }
```

However when i attempt to run i got this error?

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
at Tax.CarTax.CarTaxwithOMV(Int32 carValue)
```

I wasn't able to use string as i declared the entire webmethod as a double in either of my string declaration. Therefore, did i do anything wrong here to prevent my webservice from calling data from sql azure?

Edit : WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]

    public double CarTaxwithOMV(int carValue)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        double taxafter30k = Convert.ToDouble("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue");
        double taxafter50k = Convert.ToDouble("Select taxafter50k from TaxValue");

        double totalcartaxOMV = 0d;

            if (carValue <= 20000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = carValue;
            }
            else if (carValue > 20000 && carValue <= 50000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * taxafter30k)));
            }
            else if (carValue > 50000)
            {
                totalcartaxOMV = (20000 + 42000 + ((carValue - 50000) * taxafter50k));
            }

        return totalcartaxOMV;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the entire Tax.CarTax.CarTaxwithOMV() method. The exception is within that method. HINT: real time debugging, which is well supported by Visual Studio is your number 1 best friend forever. Also the code "double taxafter30k = Convert.ToDouble("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue");" isn't what you're actually calling right...  cause not way is that string a double.

Comment: The code --> double taxafter30k = Convert.ToDouble("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue"); --> is not going to actually do a select on the Azure DB.

Comment: no it's not :/ I ever tried this before `string taxafter30k = ("Select taxafter30k from TaxValue");` but then in my `totalcartaxOMV = ((20000 + ((carValue - 20000) * taxafter30k)));` they will say that `operation '*' cannot be applied to operands of type int and string` :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SqlCommand and SqlDataReader in conjunction with your SqlConnection. You can't just put SQL into a string and expect it to work.

There are  many many examples of how to open am SQL DB, select rows from a table, and extract their values into .NET variables (double, int, string etc.). A random example is [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jgodel/DataSetsOverview0812022005001538AM/DataSetsOverview08.aspx)